# How to initialize an array of user-defined objects with a static ID counter?

Tags: c++, static, static-methods

Here is my code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Person {
    private:
        int pancakesEaten, personID;
    public:
        Person() {
            pancakesEaten = 0;
            personID = setID();
        }

        static int setID() {
            static int currID;
            return currID++; // Returns currID and then increments.
        }

        bool operator>=(const Person& p);
        bool operator<=(const Person& p);
        void askPancakesEaten();
        void print();
};

bool Person::operator>=(const Person& p) {
    if(this->pancakesEaten >= p.pancakesEaten) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool Person::operator<=(const Person& p) {
    if(this->pancakesEaten <= p.pancakesEaten) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;   
}

void Person::askPancakesEaten() {
    std::cout << "Please enter how many pancakes you ate: ";
    std::cin >> this->pancakesEaten;
}

void Person::print() {
    std::cout << this->personID;
    std::cout << "Person " << this->personID << " ate " << this->pancakesEaten << " pancakes"; 
}

int main() {
    Person people[10];
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        Person currPerson;
        currPerson.askPancakesEaten();
        currPerson.print();
    }
}
```

My problem is that I am trying to initialize an array for  10 Person objects, and because of my static method, it is making my static count start at 10 when I enter my for loop.
I know I could get around this easily by just changing my constructor and getting rid of setID and just using i instead, but I am curious if there is another way around it?

Comment: I don't see any explanation of why we have a problem. The array default-initializes 10 people, so your static method counts them. Where's the issue?

Comment: Your question makes it sound like you know you should use `people[i]` instead of `currPerson` but you don't want to?

Comment: Why do you have a static variable? To it seems like you're trying to create an unique ID for each person you create. But that goes against what you're asking which is to not create an unique ID for every new person. So what's the logic you want? You could create a reset method that resets the ID.

Comment: What's the array for, anyway?

Comment: I see now. The answer is correct. The problem is instead of using the array of 10 Person objects you are creating additional `Person` objects in the loop, initializing and then throwing them away at each of the 10 iterations..

Comment: Unless the array is needed later I don't see a good reason why the program shouldn't create a new `Person`, print, and then discard.

Comment: `if(this->pancakesEaten >= p.pancakesEaten)  {  return true;  } return false;` could be simplified to `return (this->pancakesEaten >= p.pancakesEaten);`

Answer (score 4):

> ... but I am curious if there is another way around it.

Why are you initializing an array and don't use it in the loop then?

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    people[i].askPancakesEaten();
    people[i].print();
}
```

Besides that `setID()` is named a bit unfortunate confusing (`getNextID()` might be a better, clearer choice IMO), there's nothing wrong with that implementation as you have it.

Also it would be better to make this function `private`, since how those ID's are kept and managed to be unique for the class instances, is an implementation detail, which should't be publicly accessible.

Comment: Any benefit in moving the `getNextID()` function out of the class so it's not part of the class instance?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I don't see any, unless you would turn `currID` into a uuid or such. This ID is clearly bound to the instances of this specific class type.

Comment: Makes sense, more of an idle curiosity really. Didn't know if class size may be a consideration. But `static`is `static` I guess is the way to look at it. (now private makes it make more sense)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I've added another note what _should_ be changed in the class.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `static` members don't add anything to a claas's size.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - thank you. I wasn't sure about that. I figured that was the case, but had not chased that down to a final answer.

Comment: Hi. I see your point. I was being hardheaded and completely overlooked that. In my head, I was thinking about it as initializing an array for 10 Persons, and then from there, creating persons to be added into the respective i part of the array. It makes much more sense to just iterate over the array and edit the persons already in it.